# Website Project with Team Foundation Server

Tags: version-control, tfs, vs-web-site-project, vs-web-application-project, azure-devops

Is it possible to use a Website Project instead of a Web Application Project with Team Foundation Server? I see that it is easy to add a Web Application but cannot find how to use version control with a Website Project. Any help for this would be greatly appreciate as I have searched and have not found any solutions for this.

Comment: I expect that you _can_ do this, but _should_ you? I stay away from web site "projects" like the plague. They are strange, and are the only "project" like them in all of Visual Studio.

Comment: Well this is an existing website that I have to get working in tfs. I could look into converting to a web application but not sure how involved that would be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As John Saunders said, avoid web site projects like the plague. You can turn your site in to an application by right clicking on the site and selecting "convert to web application" but be warned that you will need to do some rework on the project structure and code.

If this isn't an option then you can add them to TFS by right clicking on the solution in solution explorer and select "Add Solution to Source Control"

This will add the solution and any projects contained within to TFS, including the web site. It will create the TFS bindings in the .sln file

Comment: Thanks that did it, just couldn't find the steps anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same boat and needed a Web Site in TFS.

My solution was to create a blank solution in TFS then add the Web Site to that solution.